# Need more status fields in Orders(Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When anyone order something through my Woocommerce website then the default functionality of woocommerce puts all orders under **“Processing”** state, I need them to land under **“Pending Approval”** status. Once I have made the order confirmation call, I will then mark them **“Processing”**. For this I need help in creating statuses through custom code in Wordpress, Then I need another status, **“Dispatch”**, for orders whose items I have already procured and are ready to be dispatched, they will be marked as **“Dispatch”**.
I am newbie in Wordpress custom coding, I know through functions.php I can control most of things through hooks, but I need help in this whole question.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: See [Order Status Manager](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-order-status-manager/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't want to use any plugin for this, Is there any guide available to create Statuses through custom coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Download the extension from your dashboard
Go to Plugins > Add New > Upload and select the ZIP file you just downloaded
Click Install Now, and then Activate
Go to WooCommerce > Settings > Order Statuses and read the next section to learn how to setup and configure the plugin.
```

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-order-status-manager/